# How to take webkit in use from androidx support library

Tags: android, androidx

How do I get webkit in use from androidx support library?

I have added this for example:

```
import androidx.webkit.WebSettings;
```

but it's not resolved

I have  added to gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
```

and to gradle.properties

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out just needed to add webkit as separate dependency in gradle.

`implementation 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.0.0'`